# typeorm 0.3.6 - db connection per request

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I’m migrating from 0.2.* to 0.3.6 version of typeorm. I’m not sure how to handle multi-tenant connections with new DataSource.
My previous implementations was based on connectionManager and it looked something like this:

```
{
    const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();

    // Check if tenant connection exists
    if (connectionManager.has(tenant.name)) {
      const connection = connectionManager.get(tenant.name);
      return Promise.resolve(
        connection.isConnected ? connection : connection.connect()
      );
    }

    // Create new tenant connection
    return createConnection({
      type: 'postgres',
      name: tenant.name,
      host: tenant.host,
      port: tenant.port,
      username: tenant.username,
      password: tenant.password,
      database: tenant.database,
      entities: [...TenantModule.entities],
    });
}
```

Connection manger is now deprecated. Maintaining my own array of connections doesn’t sound right to me.
Any ideas on how this should be handled the correct way?

Comment: Hello, did you have a solution to this? I have the same doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `typeorm: 0.3.6` `getConnection`, `createConnection` among others are deprecated. You can find migration guide in [here](https://newreleases.io/project/github/typeorm/typeorm/release/0.3.0)

to create a new connection, you will have to use `DataSource` as follows:

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host,
  port,
  username,
  password,
  database,
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: ['src/database/entity/*.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/database/migration/*.ts'],
};

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
```

where `new DataSource` is equivalent to `new Connection` and `dataSource` is equal to `getConnection`.

To check if you are connection to database, you will have utilize `AppDataSource`:

```
AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => {
    // db initialized
  })
  .catch((err: Error) => {
    throw new Error(`'Database connection error: ${err}`);
  });
```

Comment: and if you have multiple connections, just make `dataSourceOptions` as an `Array` instead of `Object`

Comment: and btw, i am using typescript in this example, if you are using javascript, you can simply omit the `DataSourceOptions `

Comment: update Deprecations:

`entities`, `migrations`, `subscribers` options inside `DataSourceOptions` accepting string directories support is deprecated. You'll be only able to pass entity references in the future versions. This means that instead of having `entities: ['src/database/entity/*.ts'],` you will have need to `entities: [UserEntity, ProfileEntity]`